# Deducing the Cayley-Hamilton theorem from the rational canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

I have the following theorem

[image]

The remarks state that it is obvious that  the caley hamilton theorem follows from this as $f_s$ is the minimal polynomial. However, I do not see why it must be that. I think that under this decomposition I can see that in the right hand side ($f_s$) will disappear, this corresponds to $f_s(\alpha)$, so I can deduce that $f_s(\alpha)=0$ (?). Therefore the minimal polynomial divides it. However I don't see how this implies that this is actually the minimal polynomial. Could someone clarify the situation for me?

**Question:** Could someone clarify why $f_s$ is the minimal polynomial here?

**Clarification:** Here we have
[image]

Comment: I’m not sure what $V_\alpha$ is

Comment: I have added a clarfication @FShrike

Comment: Also what is “$c$”

Comment: It is the companion matrix.

Comment: May I ask where those notes are from?

Comment: Hi, they are my personal notes I took during lectures/ edited from previous years

Comment: Ah ok. I thought perhaps there was a nice online book I'd missed, I haven't looked at linear algebra in quite a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_s$ will be the minimal polynomial because: if $g\in\mathcal{F}[X]$ acts as zero on $V_\alpha$, by the isomorphism of modules it must act as zero over every single one of the $\mathcal{F}[X]/(f_i)$. But that’s true if and only if it is divisible by every single $f_i$, which is true if and only if it is divisible by $f_s$.